# UseState doesn´t update a new array in the object

Tags: reactjs, object, react-hooks

I want to initiate a constant with useState, but after using this hook a part of object from http request is getting lost.

This is my code:

```
const createBlankGroups =(caunt)=>{

    const blankGroups ={
        [uuid()]:{
            name: 'Teams',
            items: teams //teams are taken from database with http request
        }
    };

    let letter = 'A'

    for(let i =0; i < caunt;i++){
        blankGroups[uuid()] = {
            name: 'Gruppe ' + letter,
            items: []
        };
        letter = String.fromCharCode(letter.charCodeAt(0)+1 )
    }
    console.log(blankGroups)

    return(blankGroups);
}
```

```
const tempGroups = createBlankGroups(3)

console.log(tempGroups) // at this step the teams are still in object (img1)

const[columns,setColumns]= useState(tempGroups);

console.log(columns); //here the array is empty (img 2)
```

[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKbXP.png)
[img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MS5WH.png)

After reserch i find a lot about useState and what it can read the unknown types of objeject, but i still dont understand how to initiate it another way.

Comment: `createBlankGroups` runs more than once

Answer (score 0):

You can use useEffect, to update the columns

```
 useEffect(() => {
 const tempGroups = createBlankGroups(3)
 setColumns(tempGroups);

},[])
```